# How to avoid invoking a promise twice?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I have the following code for simplicity:

```js
const myPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log("Called")
    resolve(10)
});

(async () => {
    console.log(await Promise.race([myPromise]))
    console.log(await Promise.all([myPromise]))
})()
```

I want to only run `myPromise` when it's passed into `race` and `all` calls. However, I see that it runs immediately, even if I remove the last block of code.

I have modified to defer the invocation by making myPromise be a function that returns a promise, but it's my understanding that I would need to invoke this twice, which would run the code twice.

```js
const myPromise = () => new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log("Called")
    resolve(10)
});

(async () => {
    console.log(await Promise.race([myPromise()]))
    console.log(await Promise.all([myPromise()]))
})()
```

What's the best thing to do here?

Comment: I'm confused by what you intend for this code to do: `Promise.race` gets a single promise, so thanks to `await` your code is blocked until that resolves, and thanks to passing a single promise, it's racing against nothing. It is functionally equivalent to `Promise.all` in this form. As such, the subsequent `Promise.all` thus becomes completely meaningless, the promise has already resolved, so `Promise.all` "does" nothing. What are you _actually_ trying to do? (i.e. please explain your real world use-case)

Comment: In the real world, it runs inside a Cloudflare Worker. Wrapping promise.all within ctx.waitUntil extends the lifetime of the worker after returning the result to the client, so it's very useful in practice. This toy example, I agree, but I want to understand the semantics.

Comment: "*I see that it runs immediately*" - what's wrong with that? You're immediately passing the promise to `Promise.race` afterwards, regardless whether you did call a function or not.

Comment: If I setup the Promise in file 1, do some processing then only later do I invoke the race, then that would be problematic.

Comment: Yes, that would be problematic indeed, but why not setup the promise only when you need it to race it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a function that caches the Promise in a closure the first time the function is run.

```js
const makePromise = (() => {
  let prom;
  return () => {
    prom ??= new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("Called")
        resolve(10)
    });
    return prom;
  };
})();
(async () => {
    console.log(await Promise.race([makePromise()]))
    console.log(await Promise.all([makePromise()]))
})()
```

But if you trust yourself enough for the use of the outer scope to not cause issues, you may as well ditch the IIFE to make things a bit simpler.

```js
let prom;
const makePromise = () => {
  prom ??= new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log("Called")
      resolve(10)
  });
  return prom;
};
(async () => {
    console.log(await Promise.race([makePromise()]))
    console.log(await Promise.all([makePromise()]))
})()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working as expected!

Comment: What's the best way to handle failures with this setup?

Comment: It's not really different from any other promise-generating function in this regard - make sure to `.catch` it somewhere the first time it's invoked.

Comment: I added an additional question because I think the actual implementation I have is slightly different